# Strange text file appeared in folder "My Pictures"

Tags: windows, security

I was programming and I went to "My Pictures" to see if my code was working.
When I was browsing the folder, I saw a text file named "fssdfsddf".
I opened the text file and I was shocked... It was full of like Chinese text
but then I went to google translate and google said that it is "Yoruba" language... Then I copied the spammed text and it said :
"Look at the light." and "Look at the blade." when I removed 1 letter.
Then I ran an AV scan to be sure.. but nothing.

Did something like this happened to any of you? 
Should I be worried?
What should I do?

PS: Here is some of the text in the file...
偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁偓䵁

Comment: It's likely not something to worry about, but I would do some basic research on google just to be sure.  There's a reason English versions of Windows randomly creates a file(s) with either all, or some, of it's contents in Chinese, however I can't recall the specific reason, only that it's not something to be concerned about as it's normal.  [Translating](https://translate.google.com) it to English shows it's gobbledygook, repeating "_Wò qiàng_"  over and over

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the quick reply... when you translate from Yoruba to English and from "Wò qiàng" remove the g, it says "Look at the light" and if you remove the last two letters, n and g it says "Look at the blade"

Comment: Right, but translating doesn't work like that, as that chronology would be Chinese -> Yoruba -> English, which would end up more coherent: _"Àfikún oníṣe fún Tuntun Lọ sí: atọka àwárí Ìjápọ mọ ojúewé ìrùsókè àwọn àkọọlẹ abuse log Lọ sí: atọka àwárí"_ -> _"User contributions for Tuntun Jump to: navigation search Jump to: navigation search"_.  Either way, a google search on Chinese characters in Windows files will likely turn up the specific reason why this occurs on English language versions of Windows

Answer (score 3):

It's not Chinese text. Your text editor is **mistakenly** interpreting the file's contents as UTF-16LE:

```
Bytes (hex):     53  50  41  4d  53  50  41  4d  ...
Codepoints:      U+5053  U+4D41  U+5053  U+4D41  ...
Characters:      偓      䵁      偓      䵁      ...
```

But the same bytes other meanings – if you tell the editor to interpret it as ASCII (or UTF-8, or any other ASCII-based encoding), you will get:

> SPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAMSPAM

```
Bytes (hex):     53  50  41  4d  53  50  41  4d  ...
Characters:      S   P   A   M   S   P   A   M   ...
```

If seen in Windows Notepad, this is an ages-old bug related to its automatic encoding detection:

- [Some files come up strange in Notepad](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040324-00/?p=40093/)
- [The Notepad file encoding problem, redux](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223/)

Comment: Hahaha. I never expected to see SPAM as the file contents. I do wonder, however, where the file came from ...